# How to organize products by collections with collections description?

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have products in my store sorted by categories. (Braslets; Rings; Earrings) It was not difficult to adapt my theme for listing products by categories.
But now I need to organize my products by collections. I have collections for example 'Spring surprise', 'Smoky winter' etc. First time I thought to assign tags to products, but I also need to show collections description, this means to show tag's description.

How can you advice me to organize products by collections? Does wp-e-commerce allow to set up a tag description?

PS. I'm newbie in wp-e-commerce and it seems to be hard for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a description field available for the `product_tag` taxonomy that can be [used in your template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description). You could also add an additional "collections" [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies) for use with the `wpsc-product` custom post type.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question.  I can't find what the variables are for single_tag_title() and tag_description( $tag_id ) for the product custom post type.  I'm using this code for the regular tag pages for regular posts and it's working:

```
<?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>

        <h1 class="pagetitle"><?php single_tag_title(); ?></h1>

<div class="catdesc"><?php echo tag_description( $tag_id ); ?>
```

But I can't figure out where I would find the variables for the products tags to make this work for product archive pages.